# Append content of a page on anchor click

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, smooth-scrolling

I am trying to write a simple jquery function that inserts the content of an html file into the current page at a specific point, and activates bootstrap's smoothscroll.js to scroll down to it when a link is clicked.

Here is my start:

Script:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
$('a').filter('[data-fetch]').click(function(e){
  var clicked = $(e.target).closest('a')
  ,   fetch = clicked.attr('data-fetch')
  ;

  $.ajax({
    url: fetch,
    success: function(data){

      $('body').append(data);
      smoothScroller(clicked.attr('href'));

    });
  });
});
    </script>
```

HTML:

```
<a href="#about" data-fetch="index-alt.html">Link</a>
```

The `#about` anchor is in the `index-alt.html` page. Is this correct?

Answer (score 2):

I think you are trying to get the attribute of clicked element so try this:

```
$('a').filter('[data-fetch]').click(function(e){
    var fetch = $(this).data('fetch'); //this here refers to the clicked element.
```

You could also just get rid of filter and do:

```
$('a[data-fetch]').click(function(e){
     var fetch = $(this).data('fetch');
```

Comment: I understand jsfiddle doesn't allow ajax; is there a platform you can recommend where I could try and demo this answer?

Comment: @RobM You could just add this in your code itself and it should work.

Answer (score 1):

Just use `.load()`

```
$('a').filter('[data-fetch]').click(function (e) {
    var url = $(this).data("fetch"); //use .data to retrieve custom data
    $("body").load(url, function() {
        console.log("data loaded");
    });
});
```

Comment: Guess he cannot use load as this will replace entire content of body with the new html. Seems like he is trying to append the new data with ajax.